# Clear auto-complete Text View if Suggestion Not Found

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have an auto-complete Text View in my app, when the user starts typing it brings up suggestions.  However when there is no suggestion meaning that the user's input does not match any data item I want the text field to clear when the user leaves focus.

I am new to Android. This is how I do my auto-complete:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.simple_list_item, busAutoCompleteList);
                            acBus.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you `AutoCompleteTextView` lost focus, simple check your `AutoCompleteTextView` datasource contains the user input data or not

```
yourAutoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // When textview lost focus check the textview data valid or not
        if (!hasFocus) {
            if (!busAutoCompleteList.contains(yourAutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString()) {
                yourAutoCompleteTextView.setText(""); // clear your TextView
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, there were one or two syntax errors in your code though. :D

Comment: Glad to hear that. if possible Hope you can edit my answer for make it better

Comment: If you are using kotlin you can call the method `view.text.clear()`